# What context do I use for a new Dialog?

Tags: java, android, button, dialog, customdialog

I need a custom dialog to appear on button press. Here is my code:

```
Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button03); 
    button3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        final Dialog custdialog = new Dialog(this);


        custdialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_drink);

        custdialog.setTitle("Custom Drink");

        custdialog.setCancelable(false);

 /etc.
```

However, on this line: final Dialog custdialog = new Dialog(this);

I get an error saying "The constructor Dialog(new View.OnClickListener(){}) is undefined".

I've tried replacing "this" with other things, but with no luck. It's odd that I get an error on this line because I have the exact same thing (except different names and stuff) in my project, beneath a switch (like this:

```
@Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
 switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.settings: 

 final Dialog settingsdialog = new Dialog(this);

    settingsdialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);

    settingsdialog.setTitle("Settings");

    settingsdialog.setCancelable(false);
```

and that one works fine... hmmm.

Comment: Did you try Context.getApplicationContext() instead of this?

Comment: I can put "getApplicationContext()" in there and it runs, but I get a FC when I press the button.

Comment: Context.getApplicationContext() instead gives me an error "Context cannot be defined"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, on your actual question, instead of `this`, use `MyActivity.this`, where `MyActivity` is the name of the `Activity` class. You are trying to use this from an inner class, but the actual object you need is the outer class.

Also, never use `getApplicationContext()` for much of anything, particularly anything related to the UI.

Comment: Thanks. I figured it would be an easy fix.